# getting error 401 unauthorized failed to validate oauth signature and token in twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am getting error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token 401 unauthorized". Here is my code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jsOauth-1.3.1.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var options={
                consumerKey: 'key',
                consumerSecret: 'secret',
                callbackUrl: 'url',
            };

            oauth=OAuth(options);
            oauth.get("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",function(data){
                requestparams=data.text;
                console.log(options);
                alert(data.text);
                window.open("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?"+data);
                },
                function(data){alert("UnAuthorized...:("+data.text);}
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume you are not using "key" and "secret" and "url" as the actual values in your options, right?

Answer (score 0):

You must get a consumerKey and consumerSecret from twitter.

To do so, go to this url: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and log in with your Twitter account (if necessary).

Then fill in the Application Details form. Once you click the "Create you Twitter application" button, you'll get the values you need to use for consumerKey and consumerSecret.